# C# using context from 2 models in one view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, database

I need help using context from 2 models in one view. I need to use `ZanrID` and `Ime` from `ZanrModel.cs`

Here is the `ZanrModel.cs` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Table("Zanr")]
    public class ZanrModel

    {
        [Key]
        public int ZanrID { get; set; }

        public string Ime { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I want to use `ZanrdID` and `Ime` in this view where I using `KnjigaModel.cs`

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.KnjigaModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Index</h2>

<a href="/Knjiga/Create" class="btn btn-warning">Dodaj novu knjigu</a>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InventarniBroj)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pisac)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Naslov)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GodinaIzdavanja)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MestoIzdavanja)
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InventarniBroj)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pisac)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Naslov)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GodinaIzdavanja)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MestoIzdavanja)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Knjiga/Izmeni/@item.KnjigaId" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Knjiga/Details/@item.KnjigaId" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Knjiga/Delete/@item.KnjigaId" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

And yes, I wanna create `dropdown menu` in `Knjiga/Create.cshtml` where users can choose what `Zanr`
they want to use it. I have databases for `Knjiga` and `Zanr` and here are the pictures of it:

[dbo.Knjiga table](https://prnt.sc/rxa2a9)

[image]

[dbo.Zanr table](https://prnt.sc/rxa2nl)

[image]

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way is create a ViewModel object to contain the two Model objects combined.

It is not a good practice to put the model direct on the view.

```
//New class outside the view.
Public class KnjigaZanrVM 
{
IEnumerable<KnjigaModel> Knjiga {get} 
IEnumerable<ZanrModel> Zanr {get}
}

//on the View
@model WebApplication1.ViewModel.KnjigaZanrVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
...
@foreach (var item in Model.Knjiga)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InventarniBroj)
        </td>
        <td>
...
foreach (var item in Model.Zanr)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZanrID)
        </td>
        <td>
...
```

See this links:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managing-data-with-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc/

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-Object-from-View-to-Controller-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: You are welcome!. If the answer resolves for you, mark it as the answer, please. Or upvote it.

Comment: You don't understand the article?, Can you read English well? The basic idea is create a new class with the two Models on it, you can pass only one class to the view.

Comment: Tell us what is your difficult, what you don't understand, and we will be happy to help.

Comment: I edited the answer, and put another article. I recommend you to start a new project as describe in the first link, doing that will help you to understand. I strong recommend you improve on the basics, write some code and be specific with the problem you find in every single step.